# Use math.isclose to compare dictionaries in python, how to implement in dictionary comprehension

Tags: python, dictionary, math, dictionary-comprehension

I'm using math.isclose to match lat/long positions within 0.05 of each other across dictionaries.

example dictA:

```
{"LATITUDE": 29.53, 
 "LONGITUDE": 105.73, 
 }
```

example dictB:

```
{"LATITUDE": 29.93, 
 "LONGITUDE": 106.13,

 }
```

For my code, I wrote the following dictionary comprehension:

```
matching_keys = dictA.keys() & dictB.keys()
z = {k: dictA[k] == dictB[k] for k in matching_keys}
print(z)
spiredictval += 1
index += 1

#matches true on lat + long + minute (timestamp)

if (z['latitude'] == True and z['longitude'] == True):
    trueMatches += 1
    #using kwargs, merge matches to one dictionary
    dict3 = {**dictA , **dictB}
    jsonoutput_list.append(dict3)
    print(dict3)
```

I'm unsure how to add `math.isclose(float(a), float(b), abs_tol=0.05)` to the dictionary comprehension. Particurarly, where Z = {k: dictA[k] == dictB[k] for k in matching_keys}.

Comment: `z['latitude'] == True and z['longitude'] == True` is never true. What did you want that to mean?

Comment: that is to mean, if the keys match between the dictionary; lat.long and the values within the key match, then do the expression below. That part of my code works, it's the above that I'm not sure about

Comment: Although if dictionary comprehensions are similar to list comprehensions then should the math.isclose be added after the if condition: [ expression for item in list if conditional ], apologies, new to python and not sure on comprehensions

Comment: @Zayn_SE Just replace the `==` comparison with it?

Comment: @Zayn_SE: dictionary comprehensions work exactly the same as list comprehensions, but with *two* expressions for each loop iteration. So instead of `[ <value_expr> for <target> in <iterable> ]`, you use `{ <key_expr>: <value_expr> for <target> in <iterable> }`, one for the key, and one for the value of each dict item. You can add `if <test>` filters and further `for <target> in <iterable>` loops to the syntax if you need to, but that's not how dict and list comprehensions differ.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to apply a different comparison method for certain keys, you need to test for that in the value expression:

```
z = {k: (
    math.isclose(float(dictA[k]), float(dictB[k]), abs_tol=0.05)
    if k in {'latitude', 'longitude'}
    else dictA[k] == dictB[k]) for k in matching_keys
}
```

That's rather verbose, so you may want to use a dispatch dictionary to store tests per key name:

```
from operator import eq

geo_close = lambda a, b: math.isclose(float(a), float(b), abs_tol=0.05)
comparisons = {
    'longitude': geo_close,
    'latitude': geo_close,
}
default_comp = eq
z = {k: comparisons.get(k, default_comp)(dictA[k], dictB[k]) for k in matching_keys}
```

The `comparisons` dictionary maps key names to a comparison function, and if the key name is not in the dictionary, [`operator.eq()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.eq) is used instead. That function does exactly the same thing as `==`.

Comment: hi martin, thank you for your help, I was able to get it once you made it click for me with your explanation above on dict_comprehnsions!